# how to make livewire v3 understand event when checkbox is clicked in loop

Tags: laravel

```
HTML
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-vcenter js-dataTable-buttons">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                            <th>Birthday</th>
                            <th>ID CARD</th>
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Checkin</th>
                            <th>Checkout</th>
                            <th>RollUp</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @livewire('admin.timekeeping.listjoin-event', ['data' => $data])
                    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
HTML COMPONENT (listjoin-event)
<div>
    @foreach ($data as $index => $row)
        <tr wire:key="row-{{ $index }}">
            <td class="fw-semibold fs-sm">{{ $row->full_name }}</td>
            <td class="fw-semibold fs-sm">
                {{ $row->gender == 0 ? 'M' : ($row->gender == 1 ? 'F' : 'Orther') }}</td>
            <td class="text-center fs-sm">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($row->birthday)->format('d-m-Y') }}
            </td>
            <td class="fs-sm">{{ $row->id_card }}</td>
            <td class="fs-sm">{{ $row->phone }}</td>
            <td class="fs-sm">{!! empty($row->checkin) || $row->checkin == null
                ? '<span class="text-danger">No checkin</span>'
                : Helper::format_date($row->checkin) !!}</td>
            <td class="fs-sm">{!! empty($row->checkout) || $row->checkout == null
                ? '<span class="text-danger">No checkout</span>'
                : Helper::format_date($row->checkout) !!}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-check form-switch form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="rollup"
                        wire:model.live="data.{{ $index }}.roll_up" {{ $row['roll_up'] ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a href="{{ route('admin.timekeeping.edit') }}/{{ $row->id }}"
                        class="btn btn-sm btn-alt-secondary js-bs-tooltip-enabled" data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                        aria-label="Edit" data-bs-original-title="Sửa">
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil-alt"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="{{ route('admin.timekeeping.delete') }}/{{ $row->id }}"
                        class="btn btn-sm btn-alt-secondary js-bs-tooltip-enabled" data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                        aria-label="Delete" data-bs-original-title="Xóa">
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-times"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

```
Notice the code below in the child component: 
<div class="form-check form-switch form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="rollup"
                        wire:model.live="data.{{ $index }}.roll_up" {{ $row['roll_up'] ? 'checked' : '' }}>
</div>
```

If i put input checkbox, text,... in the loop it doesn't call the function or any data. But if I leave them out of the loop it's completely normal. Is there any way to fix it? Video Demo: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/20269070

i found the problem but don't know how to fix it. When I put checkbox or text,... in them loop it doesn't receive data. But if I leave it outside the loop it's normal.